How to show all answer when use OR-tool solve Subset Sum Problem
I'm doing a report on NP algorithm and I'm in charge of the mathematical modeling part. I have to use OR-tool to solve SSP but it's just show one answer.
from ortools.linear_solver import pywraplp


def SubsetSumProblem():
    """Linear programming sample."""
    # Instantiate a Glop solver, naming it LinearExample.
    solver = pywraplp.Solver.CreateSolver("SAT")
    if not solver:
        return

    # Create the two variables and let them take on any non-negative value.
    nums = [10,5,7,2,6,1,7,3,8]
    target = 25
    x = {}
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        x[i] = solver.IntVar(0,1, "")

    print("Number of variables =", solver.NumVariables())

    # Constraint 0: x + 2y <= 14.

    solver.Add(sum(nums[i] * x[i] for i in range(len(nums))) == target)

    print("Number of constraints =", solver.NumConstraints())


    # Solve the system.
    print(f"Solving with {solver.SolverVersion()}")
    status = solver.Solve()

    if status == pywraplp.Solver.OPTIMAL:
        print("Solution:")
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            print(f"x{i} = ", x[i].solution_value())
    else:
        print("The problem does not have an optimal solution.")

    print("\nAdvanced usage:")
    print(f"Problem solved in {solver.wall_time():d} milliseconds")
    print(f"Problem solved in {solver.iterations():d} iterations")


SubsetSumProblem()

I want it to display all the answers but don't know how. Help me!!!
